# Is this the correct approach to design a shopping cart Android application?

Tags: android, paypal, shopping-cart, payment, token

I have a requirement to develop a shopping cart Android application.

The features should include

1. Ability for any customer to register
2. Ability to login with his credentials
3. Search and select products
4. View history about his previous purchases
5. Make payment to get the products delivered to his billing address.

I have done some analysis and below are my thoughts.

Server Side:  Java web application
Client Side:  Android application

1. Design Android application with an Activity to allow customers to register themselves.
2. Design another Activity to enable customers to login to the application (authenticate customer by sending his credentials through HttpClient to a Java servlet. Once the customer is authenticated successfully, generate a unique token id at the server end store it in the database and send it to the Android client app. Is this the correct approach to remember the customer (similar to session management) for his further interactions with the application?)
3. Provide customers the ability to search and select desired products (use above created unique token for further interaction with server).
4. Provide customers the ability to view his history of purchases.
5. Provide customers the ability to make payments. (Can i take customer PayPal credentials from Android app and use PayPal API to pragmatically make payments at server end? Is it correct approach?

Can someone please suggest me with correct approach / best practices and with sample code if possible?

Thanks,

Comment: Common guys, stop just downvoting! Tell him what's the matter! Wouldn't you want to be treated nicely too? The reason for downvotes might be: StackOverflow is a Q&A platform for specific problems while programming and coding. You're asking about design - that probably will lead to a discussion and not to the right answer (because there's no right opinion).

Comment: Yes, unfortunately this is a very open ended question (whats the correct approach / best approach). But I will say if you are doing analysis / requirements elicitation before just "slinging code" then you are on the right path. What you have so far looks good to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you well, you only need an application that is taylored to your website needs.

You suggest to use android native code and interract with your website through HTTP worker.
This provides the higher integration but is not really necessary.

Another approach is to code a [`WebApplication`](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/index.html). Mainly, this is like building your application around a [`WebView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html). Think of it as an integrated web browser with cookies, javascript and session management. With this approach you can keep as much as possible on your website (using an hidden mobile-like version) and yet add standard android widgets wherever you want.

One nice point is that you can correct part of the bugs directly on the website, without asking people to download an update.

Comment: @Prasanth it is a custom here to 'accept' and 'upvote' when you want to thank someone ;)